# Minimum number of transformations to get from one list of integers to another

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

Given the lists of sequences P and T. I'm trying to write an algorithm 
(function minNumOfTransformations(P,T) ) that returns the minimum number of moves or transformations required to get to T from P. These transformations include either substitution, insertion or deletion. E.g. to get to [0,2,4,5] from [0,1,2,3,5] requires at least 2 transformations; Adding 1 and substituting 4 with 3. I'm attempting to do this through dynamic programming on python.

```
def minNumOfTransformations(P, T):


# If first list is empty, the only option is to 
# insert all the elements
if m==0: 
     return n 

# If second list is empty, the only option is to 
# remove all the characters of the first list 
if n==0: 
    return m 

# approach here is to solve simpler sub problems but this is where I get stuck 
if P[m-1]==T[n-1]: 
    return minNumofTransformations(P[m-1], T[n-1])
```

Comment: Well, and what is your question?

Comment: please provide all of your code. Both m and n are defined outside of your question (presumably?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's stopping you from finding a ready answer on Google is probably that you don't know that what you're looking for is known as the Levenshtein distance, and is a standard metric for the difference between sequences.

There exists a [Python package](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/) built specifically to do this and implemented in C, so it'll likely be faster than whatever you write.

If you really want to do this yourself in Python, this'll help:
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Python

Comment: Thank you. For the dynamic programming approach, on Google it says that the time complexity is O(nm). Do you know why that is?